# Accessing NSDictionary problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdictionary

I'm only new to iPhone development, so my apologies if this is a silly question. I'm building various apps based on a book I'm reading and one of their suggestion was to build a mini web browser. I thought this would be easy, but while most of it is, I'm seriously struggling with the `NSDictionary`.

I have a `UISegmentedControl` used to display various bookmarks. The bookmark name that is displayed on the buttons of the `UISegmentedControl` is going to be my key and the url is the value associated with it.

I first try to declare an `NSDictonary` as a private (global variable), but since I could not get it to work, I resorted to declare it in my header file as follows:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *bookmarks;
```

I synthesize it and I initialized it in the viewDidLoad as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    bookmarks = [NSDictionary
                 dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"http://www.microsoft.com",
                                              @"Microsoft",
                                              @"http://www.google.com",
                                              @"Google",
                                              @"http://www.apple.com",
                                              @"Apple",
                                              @"http://msdn.microsoft.com",
                                              @"MSDN", nil];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

I then associated a control with my segmented control and when the event is triggered and the function is called I've got the following code which is called:

```
- (IBAction) getShortcut:(id)sender
{
  NSString *shortcut;
  shortcut = [shortcuts titleForSegmentAtIndex:shortcuts.selectedSegmentIndex];
  NSString *url = [bookmarks valueForKey:shortcut];
  //[self navigateTo: url];
  [url release];
}
```

When a button from the `UISegmentedControl` is clicked, I extract the value and stored it into shortcut and then I try to use the shortcut variable as a key to extract the associated value from the `NSDictionary` "bookmarks" but **it keeps crashing on** `NSString *url = [bookmarks valueForKey:shortcut];`
and bombs out of my function and displays the usual error EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

T.

Comment: don't release url, valueForKey: return an autoreleased object.

Comment: @Thierry - isn't it faster with a proper code highlight ?-) Welcome here is the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: @user756245... New this site and doing my best... but thanks for the tip. ;)

Answer (score 2):

That dictionary is autoreleased.

Try this:

```
self.bookmarks = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys...]
```

Comment: The only thing that matters is that you **do not own** the object returned by `dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:` as per the *Object Ownership Policy*. Whether it is autoreleased or not is a detail of the implementation.

Comment: @albertamg. Yes, that's true. Much better way to say that. +1

Answer (score 2):

You have two options. one is to deal with the *ivar* directly as @Matt S. posted. Note that in this case you need to keep you object with enough retain count. You're using and auto released object and causing the error.

The other option is to use the property you already defined:

```
self.bookmarks = [[NSDictionary ...]];
```

And the property retains it.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't retain the `NSDictionary`.

Do:

```
bookmarks = [[NSDictionary
                 dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"http://www.microsoft.com",
                                              @"Microsoft", nil] retain];
```

Comment: Provided that a property is declared, it would probably be better just to use it.

Comment: you _can_ use it, but it just the same, not _better_ ;)

Comment: ["If you are using retain and release on instance variables throughout your code, you are almost certainly doing the wrong thing."](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW1)

Comment: @albertamg - I `retain` and `release` tons of objects, almost certainly every day

Comment: Properties encapsulate memory management code and reduce boilerplate. Also, ["if you use accessor methods consistently, the chances of having problems with memory management decrease considerably."](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW1)

Comment: @albertamg - ok, no more quotes please, here is an initialization, where am I doing wrong sending a `retain` message to a freshly autoreleased object ?? the quotes you put are completly off any context. Here we **know** we are doing right.

Comment: I was just making my case in favor of using properties and I believe my quotes were totally on topic. I don't think this is *wrong*. Said that, I don't have anything else to add.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that you do not retain "bookmarks" in the viewDidLoad method. There is an naming convention mentioned somewhere in the Apple docs: If an intialisation method starts with "init..." the returned object is retained, if not you have to do it yourself. The "dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys" returns and object with retain count 0, which means, that after the scope of assignment (your viewDidLoad method) it is immediatly released again.

So just put a

```
[bookmarks retain];
```

after your initalisation and you are done. Another solution which does the retaining for you

```
bookmarks = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys ...];
```

And you shouldn't release the url in your action. It gets released, once you release the dictionary